# Dynamic TailwindCSS custom styles not applied in Next.js components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, tailwind-css

**Description:**

I'm building a Next.js app with TailwindCSS where I retrieve player data from Riot Games APIs. Using a player's "tier" data (e.g., 'EMERALD'), I aim to dynamically set a container's background color. However, certain dynamic Tailwind styles aren't being applied.

The data is retrieved like this

```
ladder rank:  [
  {
    leagueId: '<id>',
    queueType: 'RANKED_SOLO_5x5',
    tier: 'EMERALD',
    rank: 'IV',
    summonerId: '<summonerId>',
    summonerName: '<playerName>',
    leaguePoints: 0,
    wins: 65,
    losses: 61,
    veteran: false,
    inactive: false,
    freshBlood: true,
    hotStreak: false
  }
]
```

The frontend div container classname is like this

`` className={`w-48 h-64 border-4 ${data ? getRankStyles(data.tier) : ''} ...`} ``

The getRankStyles is a util function I created that looks like this

```
type Tier = 
  | 'IRON'
  | 'BRONZE'
  | 'SILVER'
  | 'GOLD'
  | 'PLATINUM'
  | 'EMERALD'
  | 'DIAMOND'
  | 'MASTER'
  | 'GRANDMASTER'
  | 'CHALLENGER';


export const getRankStyles = (rank: string) => {

    console.log("Ranked passed: ", rank)
    // switch (rank) {
    //     case 'IRON':
    return `border-${rank} bg-${rank} bg-opacity-25`;
    //     case 'BRONZE':
    //         return 'border-tier-bronze bg-tier-bronze bg-opacity-25';
    //     case 'SILVER':
    //         return 'border-tier-silver bg-tier-silver bg-opacity-25';
    //     case 'GOLD':
    //         return 'border-tier-gold bg-tier-gold bg-opacity-25';
    //     case 'PLATINUM':
    //         return 'border-tier-platinum bg-tier-platinum bg-opacity-25';
    //     case 'EMERALD':
    //         return 'border-tier-emerald bg-tier-emerald bg-opacity-25';
    //     case 'DIAMOND':
    //         return 'border-tier-diamond bg-tier-diamond bg-opacity-25';
    //     case 'MASTER':
    //         return 'border-tier-master bg-tier-master bg-opacity-25';
    //     case 'GRANDMASTER':
    //         return 'border-tier-grandmaster bg-tier-grandmaster bg-opacity-25';
    //     case 'CHALLENGER':
    //         return 'border-tier-challenger bg-tier-challenger bg-opacity-25';
    //     default:
    //         return 'border-gray-400 bg-gray-400';
    // }
}
```

I included the commented out code to show other ways I've tried to solve this issue.

**Tailwind Configuration:**

In tailwind.config.js, I've added custom colors under theme.extend.colors and other related properties. For example:

**Issues Observed:**

-Custom styles from tailwind.config.js don't seem to apply dynamically to the className according to the player's tier.
-Fixed styles work fine.

**Steps Tried:**

1. I've verified that there are no errors in the browser developer tools. The elements tab show the class being applied. But the Styles tab does not show the styles. There doesn't seem to be any overlapping styles either.
2. Checked postcss.config.js for correct plugins.
3. Played around with the content array in tailwind.config.js and tried disabling purging.
4. Ensured proper TailwindCSS integration with Next.js.

Any insights or suggestions would be appreciated.

**This is my tailwind.config file**

```
import type { Config } from 'tailwindcss'

const config: Config = {
  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        'riot-dark': '#2D2D2D',
        riot: {
          primaryRed: '#d13639',
          secondaryRed: '#F12B15',
          black: '#000000',
          grayBlack: '#2D2D2D',
          white: '#FFFFFF'
        },
        lol: {
          primaryBlue: '#0bc6e3',
          lighterBlue: '#CDFAFA',
          darkerBlue: '#0A1428',
          functionalityGold: '#e0b667',
          lolbutton: '#0AC8B9',
          lolbuttonHover: '#0A323C',
          buttonText: '#0A323C',
          buttonTextHover: '#0AC8B9',
        },
        borderColor: {
          IRON: '#43464B',
          BRONZE: '#8B4513',
          SILVER: '#C0C0C0',
          GOLD: '#FFD700',
          PLATINUM: '#E5E4E2',
          EMERALD: '#50C878',
          DIAMOND: '#1E90FF',
          MASTER: '#9932CC',
          GRANDMASTER: '#4169E1',
          CHALLENGER: '#00008B', 
        },
        backgroundColor: {
          'riot-card': '#5B5A56',
          'riot-red': '#ff4248',
          'riot-gray1': '#A09B8C',
          'riot-gray1.5': '#5B5A56',
          'riot-gray2': '#3C3C41',
          'riot-gray3': '#1E2328',
          IRON: '#43464B',
          BRONZE: '#8B4513',
          SILVER: '#C0C0C0',
          GOLD: '#FFD700',
          PLATINUM: '#E5E4E2',
          EMERALD: '#50C878',
          DIAMOND: '#1E90FF',
          MASTER: '#9932CC',
          GRANDMASTER: '#4169E1',
          CHALLENGER: '#00008B',
        },
        backgroundImage: {
          'gradient-radial': 'radial-gradient(var(--tw-gradient-stops))',
          'gradient-conic':
            'conic-gradient(from 180deg at 50% 50%, var(--tw-gradient-stops))',
      }
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
export default config;
```

Comment: Maybe try 'border-color-{rank}' and 'background-color-{rank}'

Comment: @PrateekChachra did not resolve the issue. the elements show border-color-EMERALD and bg-color-EMERALD now but the styles tab doesn't show any colors being applied.

Comment: I see it now, the 'borderColor' object is inside the 'colors'. Take it out maybe in the main 'extends' object and then try?

Comment: that worked, thank you so much! Could you please convert your comment into an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

The 'borderColor' object is inside the 'colors'. Take it out maybe in the main 'extends' object and then try?